# Logic for xsl:for is not clear

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input :-

```
<b>
<cac:OrderLine>

        <cac:LineItem>
            <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Quantity unitCode="KGM">100</cbc:Quantity>
                    <cbc:TotalTaxAmount currencyID="GBP">17.50</cbc:TotalTaxAmount>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="GBP">100.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
                 <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="KGM">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
            </cac:Price>
            </cac:LineItem>
                 </cac:OrderLine>
<cac:OrderLine>
    <cac:LineItem>
            <cbc:ID>5</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Quantity unitCode="KGM">300</cbc:Quantity>
                    <cbc:TotalTaxAmount currencyID="GBP">100.50</cbc:TotalTaxAmount>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="GBP">2000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
                 <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="KGM">52</cbc:BaseQuantity>
            </cac:Price>
            </cac:LineItem>
                 </cac:OrderLine>
```

Actually This is the input Structure ,And If we apply Loop like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="b/OrderLine/LineItem">
```

It should Only pick the First Lineitem But its picking all the line items present in the Input ? Can anybody please explain the functionality of xsl:for-each here.

Because The Loop should be applied to upto Order itself,But How the above written code is picking all the line-items present in the Input file

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the first `LineItem` only, do not use `xsl:for-each`. Use

```
<xsl:template match="b/OrderLine/LineItem[1]">
    ....
</xsl:template>
```

as the name implies `for-each`, it processes every item that matches the `select` expression

Answer (score 1):

to be very specific to your question:

1) you have not mentioned where

```
<b>
```

is ending

2)if your xpath is selecting all the nodes then certainly it would be the root node of document.

3) `<xsl:for-each select="b/OrderLine/LineItem">`

the name itself justifies that the logic will be applied to "**EACH**" element where your xpath is pointing

Answer (score 0):

Well your XPath says: "find me all `b` nodes and then, within, all `OrderLine` nodes and then, within, all `LineItem` nodes. So yes, this is expected functionality.

Sidenote: you should be using templates rather than a `for-each`. (ForEach is what a developers use when they come to XSLT from other languages.)

If you want only the first `LineItem` node within each `OrderLine` then a quick modification is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="b/OrderLine/LineItem[1]">
```

[Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/Z3oLAV).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 xsl:for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="b/OrderLine">
    <!-- loop for each OrderLine -->
    <xsl:for-each select="LineItem">
    <!-- loop for each LineItem -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```